# GSON adding quotes to returned String object

Tags: java, gson

Im sending an object from client to server via a post command. When GSON returns it has incorrectly added quotes to the start and end of the returned String.

This is the code:

Client code:

```
public void getUserRole(){
    Form form = new Form();
    form.add("username", "Testuser");
    form.add("firstname", "Test");
    form.add("lastname", "User");
    form.add("userGroup", "Admin");
    form.add("userGroup", "Normal");

    String userGroupStr = "";

    try {
        userGroupStr = client.post("/rest/login/", "getUserRole", MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED, String.class, form), 

        //Inspection of userGroupStr  object has role set to: "Admin" when it returns
    }
}

public <T> T post(final String uriExtension, final String path, final String mediaType, final Class<T> returnType,
    final Object postData) {
    return post(uriExtension, path, mediaType, returnType, null, postData);
}
```

Server Code:

```
@POST
@Path("getUserRole")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@PermitAll
public String getUserRole(@Context HttpServletRequest req,
    @FormParam("username") String username,
    @FormParam("firstname") String firstname,
    @FormParam("lastname") String lastname,
    @FormParam("userGroup") List<String> userGroups) throws Throwable {

    //Stripped out code which essentially sets role to Admin for testing purposes
    String role = "Admin";

    //Inspection of object has role set to: Admin
    return role;
}
```

If someone could tell me how to stop it adding an extra pair of quotes to the returned object that would be much appreciated!!

Thanks,

Comment: Could you show the piece of code where do you call Gson?

Comment: This thread can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639482/json-string-from-gson-remove-double-quotes