# JSON string from Gson: remove double quotes

Tags: java, json, gson

Here is an example of my Json code:

```
array("id" => 0, "navn" => "Vind telefon", "udgiver" => "Telia", "beskrivelse" => utf8_encode("Vind en Iphone 5 ved at gætte 1 spørgsmål"), "tilmeldte" => 89, "startdate" => "10-04-2013", "enddate" => "30-06-2013"),
```

If I print out the `navn` attribute in my program i get the following output:

```
"Vind Telefon"
```

As you can see it keeps the double quotes.

Is there any way I can avoid that?

**My full code:**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: json; charset=utf-8');
$lottery = array(
    array("id" => 0, "navn" => "Vind telefon", "udgiver" => "Telia", "beskrivelse" => utf8_encode("Vind en Iphone 5 ved at gætte 1 spørgsmål"), "tilmeldte" => 89, "startdate" => "10-04-2013", "enddate" => "30-06-2013"),
    array("id" => 1, "navn" => "Fri taletid", "udgiver" => "Telmore", "beskrivelse" => utf8_encode("Vind et års forbrug af fri data og fri taletid"), "tilmeldte" => 701, "startdate" => "03-03-2013", "enddate" => "10-06-2013"),
    array("id" => 2, "navn" => "Vind 5000 kr.", "udgiver" => "Bilka", "beskrivelse" => utf8_encode("Vind et gavekort på 5000 kr til bilka."), "tilmeldte" => 101, "startdate" => "10-05-2013", "enddate" => "01-07-2013"),
    array("id" => 3, "navn" => "Fri vin", "udgiver" => "Føtex", "beskrivelse" => utf8_encode("Vind et års forbrug af vin"), "tilmeldte" => 391, "startdate" => "01-04-2013", "enddate" => "10-07-2013"),
    array("id" => 4, "navn" => "Vind et TV", "udgiver" => "El-giganten", "beskrivelse" => utf8_encode("Vind et 60\" LED tv til stuen"), "tilmeldte" => 22, "startdate" => "01-04-2013", "enddate" => "22-07-2013"),
    array("id" => 5, "navn" => "Vind en telefon", "udgiver" => "Samsung", "beskrivelse" => utf8_encode("Vind en Galaxy S4 4g telefon"), "tilmeldte" => 784, "startdate" => "10-04-2013", "enddate" => "30-07-2013"),
    array("id" => 6, "navn" => "Gratis Vand", "udgiver" => "Aqua D'or", "beskrivelse" => utf8_encode("Vind et helt års forbrug af vand og dansk vand"), "tilmeldte" => 345, "startdate" => "01-03-2013", "enddate" => "18-07-2013"),
    array("id" => 7, "navn" => "Fri Adwords", "udgiver" => "Google", "beskrivelse" => utf8_encode("Vind adwords kuponner til en værdi af 10.000"), "tilmeldte" => 22, "startdate" => "10-02-2013", "enddate" => "22-08-2013"),
    array("id" => 8, "navn" => "Morgenmads produkter", "udgiver" => "Kellogs", "beskrivelse" => utf8_encode("Vind et helt års forbrug af kellogs produkter"), "tilmeldte" => 111, "startdate" => "01-05-2013", "enddate" => "10-09-2013"),
    array("id" => 9, "navn" => utf8_encode("Vind tøj for 10.000"), "udgiver" => "Jack & Jones", "beskrivelse" => utf8_encode("Vind et gavekort til Jack & Jones på 10.000"), "tilmeldte" => 33, "startdate" => "03-05-2013", "enddate" => "01-10-2013"),
);
//id, navn, udgiver, beskrivelse, tilmeldte, startdate, slutdate
echo json_encode($lottery);
?>
```

The java code printing it out:

```
        String discription = arrayListing.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("beskrivelse").toString();
    System.out.println(discription);
```

**My full java code**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String result = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.marcrasmussen.dk/json.php");
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
        for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
            System.out.println(line);
            result = line;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Ignore
            }
        }
    }

    JsonElement root = new JsonParser().parse(result);


    HashMap<Integer,CompetetionObject> comMap = new HashMap<>();

    JsonArray arrayListing = root.getAsJsonArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < root.getAsJsonArray().size(); i++) {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(arrayListing.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("id").toString());
        String name = arrayListing.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("navn").toString();
        String provider = arrayListing.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("udgiver").toString();
        String discription = arrayListing.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("beskrivelse").toString();
        int signedUp = Integer.parseInt(arrayListing.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("tilmeldte").toString());
        String startDate = arrayListing.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("startdate").toString();
        String endDate =  arrayListing.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("enddate").toString();
        CompetetionObject co = new CompetetionObject(id, name, provider, discription, signedUp, startDate, endDate);
        String day = startDate.substring(1, 3);
        String month = startDate.substring(5,6);
        String year = startDate.substring(7,startDate.length()-1);
        DateTime d = new DateTime(year+"-"+month+"-"+day);
        System.out.println(discription);
        comMap.put(id, co);
    }
}
```

**The output of my Java program:**

```
    [{"id":0,"navn":"Vind telefon","udgiver":"Telia","beskrivelse":"Vind en Iphone 5 ved at g\u00e6tte 1 sp\u00f8rgsm\u00e5l","tilmeldte":89,"startdate":"10-04-2013","enddate":"30-06-2013"},{"id":1,"navn":"Fri taletid","udgiver":"Telmore","beskrivelse":"Vind et \u00e5rs forbrug af fri data og fri taletid","tilmeldte":701,"startdate":"03-03-2013","enddate":"10-06-2013"},{"id":2,"navn":"Vind 5000 kr.","udgiver":"Bilka","beskrivelse":"Vind et gavekort p\u00e5 5000 kr til bilka.","tilmeldte":101,"startdate":"10-05-2013","enddate":"01-07-2013"},{"id":3,"navn":"Fri vin","udgiver":null,"beskrivelse":"Vind et \u00e5rs forbrug af vin","tilmeldte":391,"startdate":"01-04-2013","enddate":"10-07-2013"},{"id":4,"navn":"Vind et TV","udgiver":"El-giganten","beskrivelse":"Vind et 60\" LED tv til stuen","tilmeldte":22,"startdate":"01-04-2013","enddate":"22-07-2013"},{"id":5,"navn":"Vind en telefon","udgiver":"Samsung","beskrivelse":"Vind en Galaxy S4 4g telefon","tilmeldte":784,"startdate":"10-04-2013","enddate":"30-07-2013"},{"id":6,"navn":"Gratis Vand","udgiver":"Aqua D'or","beskrivelse":"Vind et helt \u00e5rs forbrug af vand og dansk vand","tilmeldte":345,"startdate":"01-03-2013","enddate":"18-07-2013"},{"id":7,"navn":"Fri Adwords","udgiver":"Google","beskrivelse":"Vind adwords kuponner til en v\u00e6rdi af 10.000","tilmeldte":22,"startdate":"10-02-2013","enddate":"22-08-2013"},{"id":8,"navn":"Morgenmads produkter","udgiver":"Kellogs","beskrivelse":"Vind et helt \u00e5rs forbrug af kellogs produkter","tilmeldte":111,"startdate":"01-05-2013","enddate":"10-09-2013"},{"id":9,"navn":"Vind t\u00f8j for 10.000","udgiver":"Jack & Jones","beskrivelse":"Vind et gavekort til Jack & Jones p\u00e5 10.000","tilmeldte":33,"startdate":"03-05-2013","enddate":"01-10-2013"}]
"Vind en Iphone 5 ved at gætte 1 spørgsmål"
"Vind et års forbrug af fri data og fri taletid"
"Vind et gavekort på 5000 kr til bilka."
"Vind et års forbrug af vin"
"Vind et 60\" LED tv til stuen"
"Vind en Galaxy S4 4g telefon"
"Vind et helt års forbrug af vand og dansk vand"
"Vind adwords kuponner til en værdi af 10.000"
"Vind et helt års forbrug af kellogs produkter"
"Vind et gavekort til Jack & Jones på 10.000"
```

Comment: That's not JSON.

Comment: Nope. It's not Java because is PHP.

Comment: @marc could you provide a sample of the code you use to make the output?

Comment: @jsve JSON is not a subset of JavaScript, it's a *notation* that's *based on* a subset of JavaScript (object syntax, for example)

Comment: @MarcRasmussen can you show us the code that's printing it out?

Comment: Updated my code to match the requests

Comment: How does `arrayListing` gets its value?

Comment: @DekDekku im using GSON

Comment: Added my full java code

Comment: @MarcRasmussen how about the full output of your Java code?  You have some lines that are printing all the input; show what they print.

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot added my output

Comment: Anyone able to tell me how i can get rid of the double qoutation marks?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

It's not documented properly, but `JsonElement#toString()` gets you a string that represents the JSON element and would be appropriate for re-creating the JSON serialization.  What you want is `JsonElement#getAsString()`.  This will throw an error if you're not looking at a string, but if you are, you'll get the string value.

Here's a test program to demonstrate:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String in = "{\"hello\":\"world\"}";
        System.out.println(in);
        JsonElement root = new JsonParser().parse(in);
        System.out.println(root.getAsJsonObject().get("hello").toString());
        System.out.println(root.getAsJsonObject().get("hello").getAsString());
    }
}
```

And its output:

```
{"hello":"world"}
"world"
world
```

Comment: Our answer are both relevant. You answer however is simpler than mine.

Comment: :-)  JAXB is cool, but I think I'd do `discription.substring(1, discription.length()-1)` before converting JSON into XML just for the output.

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot oh thanx a lot for your demonstration!!! i was searching for the solution from last three days.

Comment: Thank you! Just as I was about to think I'm crazy

Comment: sometimes it is difficult to catch this, thanks for the answer

Comment: So then...would extending `JsonObject` and overriding `toString()` to say `return this.getAsString()` be likely to break things?  Or in other words, does Gson rely upon this wonky behavior of `toString()` internally or is this just a weird design decision affecting a public portion of the API that users are free to subvert at-will?

Answer (score 0):

To put object or array properties into your JsonObject and get them back as objects and arrays (not as string), use the approach:

```
new JsonObject().add(
  "mySubobject",
  new Gson().toJsonTree(
    new JsonObject()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StringTypeSerializationAdapter extends TypeAdapter<String> {


public String read(JsonReader reader) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

public void write(JsonWriter writer, String value) throws IOException {
    if (value == null) {
        writer.nullValue();
        return;
    }
    writer.jsonValue(value);
}
}
```

above will help you removing double quotes across strings. this is using GSON library