# .equal in strings from json?

Tags: java, json, deserialization

I'm trying some code where I want to compare strings i've grabbed from json to certain values. However the if statements never trigger. I have confirmed the values of the instances are set properly, and can be printed out.

```
    //MAKING CLASSES
    Collection collection = new ArrayList();

    Event ev = new Event();
    ev.name = "sven";
    ev.source = "src10";

    Event2 ev2 = new Event2();
    ev2.name = "type";
    ev2.data = "somedata";

    collection.add(ev);
    collection.add(ev2);

    //MAKING A BUNCH OF CLASSES TO JSON
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(collection);
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonArray array = parser.parse(json).getAsJsonArray();

    //JSON TO JAVA
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {

        JsonObject nameObject = array.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
        String nameString = nameObject.get("name").toString();

        if (nameString.equals("sven")) {
            System.out.println("this is sven");
            Event event = gson.fromJson(array.get(i), Event.class);

        }

        else if (nameString.equals("type")) {
            System.out.println("this is type");
            Event2 event2 = gson.fromJson(array.get(i), Event2.class);

        }

        else{
            System.out.println("nothing");
        }


    }
```

Comment: A JSON string will be double-quoted. This is addressed at [JSON string from Gson: remove double quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639482/json-string-from-gson-remove-double-quotes).

Comment: this solved it. Just escaping the quotes.

Answer (score 2):

According Gson API your call to 'nameObject.get("name")' will return [JsonElement](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html). This means you should use 'getAsString()' method instead of 'toString()':

```
String nameString = nameObject.get("name").getAsString();
```

'toString()' method is designed (in general) for debugging purposes. And should be used very carefully in program logic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that the implementation of toString() in JsonElement class is such that it will return the String inclusive of "".

To make it easier to understand look into the following code

> JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
>
> json.addProperty("hello", "tata");
>
> System.out.println(json.get("hello").toString()); // Prints "tata"
>
> System.out.println(json.get("hello").getAsString()); // Prints tata

so internally your code is comparing "sven" and sven which will return not equal